# Handling Multiple Tabs Sessioning using session variable

Tags: php, html, session

Hey guys i was asked to do this exercise as a part of my curriculum by my staffs. So what the exercise is all about is having a login page named index.php and having a login form for it. Now what i am asked to do is like use a session variable as my control variable. If say i open a new tab in my browser and access the same file then i should get the login success page and not the login form. And the login success page consists of a logout button which on clicking, the variable will be unset. In simple terms i can tell u this:

```
if session!=''
show success
else
show form
```

Here is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Login Form</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
<?php
session_start();
$link = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
$db_selected = mysqli_select_db($link,'tpf');
if(isset($_POST['login']))
    {
    $_SESSION['id']=$_POST['id'];
    $_SESSION['pass']=$_POST['pass'];
    date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Calcutta');
    $date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    $id = $_SESSION['id'];
    $pass = $_SESSION['pass'];
    $in=mysqli_query($link,"SELECT * from login where id='$id' and password='$pass'");
    $count=mysqli_num_rows($in);
    if($count==1)
    {
    $sql2="SELECT * FROM login WHERE id='$id'";
    $result = mysqli_query($link,$sql2);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    $person=$row['name'];
    $no=$row['id'];
    $last=$row['time'];
    if($last=='')
    {
    $last="first login";
    }
    $up=mysqli_query($link,"UPDATE Login SET `time`='$date' where id='$id'");
    echo "<div class='login'><form method='post' action=''>";
    echo "<center>ID : $no <br><br> Name : $person <br><br> Last Login : $last <br>";
    echo "<p><input type='submit' name='back' value='back'></p></center></form></div>";
    }
    }
    else
    {
    echo "<div class='login'><form method='post' action=''>";
    echo "<h1>EMPLOYEE LOGIN</h1><p><font size='2'>Login &nbsp ID:</font> <input type='text' name='id' id='id' placeholder='Login ID'></p>";
    echo "<p><font size='2'>Password:</font> <input type='password' name='pass' id='pass' placeholder='Password'></p>";
    echo "<p class='submit'><input type='submit' name='login' value='login'></p></form>";
    echo "<form method='post' action='register.php'>";
    echo "<p class='submit'><font size='2'>New User? &nbsp </font><input type='submit' name='change' value='sign up'></p></form></div>";
    }
mysqli_close($link);
?>
</body>
</html>
```